# Erasing and re-creating elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, boilerplate

I am using the jquery plugin boilerplate ([available here](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/)) to create an extension of the div element. The plugin is meant to add other divs or elements inside the original div. My problem is that I would like to be able to destroy and re-create the elements inside the div.

Here is a simplified example of the the plugin code:

```
(function($) {

$.extension = function(element, options) {

    var defaults = {
        foo: 'bar',
        onFoo: function() {}
    }

    var plugin = this;

    plugin.settings = {}

    var $element = $(element),
         element = element;

    plugin.init = function() {
        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        // code goes here

        var newDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
        newDiv.html("hello world");

        $element.append(newDiv);
    }

    plugin.foo_public_method = function() {
        // code goes here
    }

    var foo_private_method = function() {
        // code goes here
    }

            plugin.destroy = function () {
        $element.empty();
    }

    plugin.init();

}

$.fn.extension = function(options) {

    return this.each(function() {
        if (undefined == $(this).data('extension')) {
            var plugin = new $.extension(this, options);
            $(this).data('extension', plugin);
        }
    });

}

})(jQuery);
```

As you can see I use the jquery empty() method to erase the children of the div. It erases fine but then I am not able to re-create them.

Here is the html code used to call the plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/extension.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id="destroy">Destroy</button>
<button type="button" id="create">Create</button>
<div id="random" ></div>

<script>
$('#random').extension();
$('#destroy').click(function(){
$('#random').data('extension').destroy();
});

$('#create').click(function(){
alert("hey");
$('#random').extension();
 });

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the old data so the plugin isn't recreated because it won't be `== undefined`

Try

```
plugin.destroy = function () {
    $element.empty().removeData("extension");
};
```